# How to redirect to "ErrorPage" if exception occurs in "beforePhase" method?

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, oracle-adf

How to redirect to "ErrorPage" if exception occurs in "beforePhase"?. When i try to re-direct its giving me an "Response Already Committed".

Regards
Raj

Comment: Why don't you show the relevant code of how you're trying to redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Check if below code helps you,

```
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent e)
{
 try
  {
    //if something doesn't work here

  } 
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println("Exception ocurred in beforePhase method");
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
            UIViewRoot newPage = context.getApplication().getViewHandler().createView(context,"/pages/techErrorPage.jsf");
            context.setViewRoot(newPage);
            context.renderResponse();
  }
}
```